# How to find out which app the user has chosen from chooser?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to share some data (an image and some text) and I want to know if the user has chosen "Facebook" from a list of available apps. If that's the case, I want to do something other than run Facebook app, because the Facebook app blocks `EXTRA_TEXT` and `EXTRA_SUBJECT` and `EXTRA_TITLE`.

I'm starting it like this

```
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent , "Share with: "), CODE);
```

But the onResult is called **after** the app that the user chose is finished running and I'm back to my activity.

Comment: We had the same issue at my workplace and we've solved it by creating our own class that behaved exactly like intent chooser. When you are having your own chooser then it's easy to achieve that. But I can't post here source code of it since it is not exclusively mine, sorry.

Comment: @LubošStaráček Thanks, I was thinking about that. I guess I have no choice :/